# Why accessibility add NSString property as static text? And how to ignore it?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsstring, accessibility, voiceover

I have a custom UITableViewCell called ReplyCell. Here's the code:

TSSmartReplyCell.h

```
@interface TSSmartReplyCell : UITableViewCell
@end
```

TSSmartReplyCell.m

```
@interface TSSmartReplyCell ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *replyID;
@end
```

From Xcode Accessibility Inspector:

[image]
[image]

Why accessibility add the NSString property and read it out by VoiceOver? How to ignore it?

I tried to add self.isAccessibilityElement = NO in awakeFromNib but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why accessibility add the NSString property and read it out by VoiceOver?

The added property is seen as part of the content of the cell, that's why the screen reader reads it out as a default accessible element.

> How to ignore it?

Define the [accessibilityElements](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-16202.html#accessibilityElements) array of the cell to define its elements to be interpreted by VoiceOver as accessible for instance.